# thinkpad_ec fails to load after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, hardware, battery, thinkpad

After upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I now cannot load the `thinkpad_ac` module (which is transitively required by `tp_smapi`):

```
[ 4245.656402] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_request_row: arg0 rejected: (0x01:0x00)->0x00
[ 4245.656404] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_read_row: failed requesting row: (0x01:0x00)->0xfffffffb
[ 4245.656406] thinkpad_ec: initial ec test failed
```

This is on a Lenovo ThinkPad T480s. Without `tp_smapi` loaded, `tlp` no longer allows me to change the charging limits.

**How do I re-enable `tp_smapi` and all its transitive dependencies, so that `tlp` can work again?**

Comment: Could be a bug in upstream: https://github.com/linux-thinkpad/tp_smapi/issues/36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a serious misunderstanding on your part:

1. tp_smapi and thinkpad_ec were *never* compatible with your hardware. The last ThinkPad generation supporting tp_smapi is T420/X220 (released 8 years ago!).
2. TLP – or more precisely TLP's battery features – work happily without tp-smapi. Please refer to the FAQ: https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#which-kernel-module-do-i-need-for-my-hardware

Comment: You are right! I mistakenly thought I need `tp_smapi` &c. because `tlp fullcharge` doesn't work after the upgrade, and `tlp-stat -b` shows that `tp_smapi` is not loaded. But I experimented with it further and it turns out **the real bug is in `tlp`**: `tlp fullcharge`, or setting the max charge to `100` using `tlp  setcharge`, doesn't work! It seems **99 percent is the maximum allowed value** -- I guess there's an off-by-1 error somewhere in `tlp` introduced between the 18.04 and the 20.04 versions.

Comment: You seem to tend to jump to conclusions. There is definitely no off-by-1 error for thresholds, instead there are several "quirks" in Lenovos firmware. Did you check the [FAQ](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html) yet? Please attach the output of `tlp-stat -c -s -b` to your question.

Comment: i think at this point I'm better off going to the `tlp` issue tracker instead and reporting what I'm seeing.

Comment: You can save the detour, I can clear this up here too.

Comment: well it wasn't obvious to me that you're a TLP developer. Anyways, I've uploaded the output of `tlp-stat -c -s -b` and also a transcript showing `tlp fullcharge` failing, to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/128bb4ee7e766da639651f53122d60d4).

Comment: What you observe is a known EC firmware bug, see [FAQ](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#disabling-the-charge-thresholds-does-not-work). Because of your way outdated BIOS version (1.11 vs 1.39) `fwupdmgr` may refuse to update. Try either the manual method described in [Lenovo's README for Linux](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t480s-type-20l7-20l8/downloads/ds502226) or use an [USB stick](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/update-lenovo-bios-from-linux-usb-stick-pen/). Good luck.