# TLP shows no drivers loaded

Tags: 20.04, battery, thinkpad, dkms

Ever since [clearing up this misunderstanding](https://askubuntu.com/q/1250170/10154) I've been able to use TLP running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Thinkpad T480s. However, I have now noticed that something (probably some DKMS upgrade?) has broken it, as I can no longer change its settings.

`tlp-stat -b` shows that none of the interfaces are available:

```
+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = inactive (laptop not supported)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (laptop not supported)
tp-smapi   = inactive (laptop not supported)
```

I can see that `acpi_call` is loaded:

```
# lsmod|grep acpi
acpi_call              16384  0
```

Removing and reloading it doesn't complain, albeit there is absolutely no output in `dmesg`, `syslog`, or `kern.log` (I was hoping to see something about a successful load):

```
# rmmod acpi_call
# lsmod |grep acpi_call
# modprobe acpi_call
# lsmod |grep acpi_call
acpi_call              16384  0
```

I have already tried `dpkg-reconfigure acpi-call-dkms`.

How do I get TLP working again?

Answer (score 0):

[Based on this part of the documentation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#which-kernel-module-do-i-need-for-my-hardware), I have solved this with `modprobe thinkpad_acpi`. I don't know why this module used to be loaded on my 20.04 system and isn't anymore.